# adding background image to the nnavigation rootview

Tags: iphone, xcode, background-image, navigationcontroller

how to add image as background to my rootview in navigation controller programmatically...

thanks for that answer for navigation bar hide,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];`
 in viewDidLoad